# How java split() exactly works?

Tags: java, split

why using `split()` in java works differently?
I want to split a version string like this: 1.2.3.4 however if I do like this: will get an empty array,, if I use `split("\\.")`, it works as my expected:

```
        String version1 = "1.2.3.4.5";
        String version2 = "1.2.3.4.5.6";
        String[] v1Arr = version1.split("."); 
        String[] v2Arr = version2.split("\\."); 
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(v1Arr)); // [] why?
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(v2Arr)); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]


String version1 = "1-2-3-4-5";
String version2 = "1-2-3-4-5-6";
String[] v1Arr = version1.split("-");
String[] v2Arr = version2.split("\\-");

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(v1Arr)); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(v2Arr)); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

If I change "." to "-" both work as expected, why does this happens? Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is explained in the javadocs for String.split and Pattern.  The former says that the split argument is a regex, and the latter says what "." means in a regex.  I recommend looking up the javadocs and reading them as a good (i.e. quicker!) way to get answers to questions about the Java APIs.  The javadocs are linked from the Java release notes, and can easily be fount using Google.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.` is a special pattern token in a regular expression. It matches any one character. When you split on every possible character you get an empty array (because there is nothing left). In contrast, when you escape the `.` with `\\.` the token is rendered as a literal (and only matches a literal `.`).

Comment: It is work noting that this explained in the javadoc.

Answer (score 3):

\ is called escape character and . dot interpreted as escape character so you are not able to use dot directly to split an string

that’s why you have to use \ as escape character with dot , to represent as dot in string

Answer (score 2):

Just as an alternative to the @Elliott Frisch answer, you may also split on a character or characters contained within a regex character class.  Consider the following code snippet:

```
String version = "1.2.3.4.5.6";
String[] parts = version.split("[.]");
```

The square brackets tell the regex engine to treat whatever is inside as a literal character, in this case, a literal dot.  This approach can be even more useful when trying to split on several characters, many of which are perhaps meta characters.  Using bracket notation, we don't have to worry about special escaping syntax.

Comment: Thank you! Strongly agree and I think "[]" is a little bite easy to remember