# This program is not showing correct output

Tags: java

**Code:**

```
public class StringBuffer_Filtering_data 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String [] records={
                 "1001.ajay.manager.account.45000.male.38",
                 "1002.aiswrya.clerk.account.25000.female.30",
                 "1003.varun.manager.sales.50000.male.35",
                 "1004.amit.manager.account.47000.male.40",
                 "1005.kareena.executive.sales.15000.female.24",
                 "1006.deepak.clerk.sales.23000.male.30",
                 "1007.sunil.accountant.sales.13000.male.29",
                 "1008.satvik.director.purchase.80000.male.45"
                 }; 
        StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer(255);
        for(String record:records)
        {
            String[] fields=record.split(".");
            if(fields[2].equals("manager"))
            {
                System.out.println(record);
            }
        }
        

    }
}
```

**Expected output:**

> 1001,ajay,manager,account,45000,male,38
> 1003,varun,manager,sales,50000,male,35
> 1004,amit,manager,account,47000,male,40

Comment: Terrible title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3481828/642706), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52214418/642706), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32715552/642706), and likely more.

Comment: Please see this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833008/java-string-split-with-dot

Answer (score 2):

`split`'s argument is a regular expression (regex), not a plain old string. In the context of a regex, `.` is a special character while means "any character". If you want to split the string by the literal `.`, you'll need to escape it:

```java
String[] fields=record.split("\\.");
// Here ----------------------^^
```